Do electric hot air balloons exist?
With many things going electric these days, I wonder, is there an electric hot air balloon? One that doesn't use propane tanks to heat the balloon air.

I can't imagine that working very well. Batteries are heavy, and unlike propane (or similar fuels) the batteries don't get lighter as they discharge.

It really does seem a terrible idea.  I'm all for electric aircraft, but I think the best way to use batteries for a hot air balloon would be to set them on fire...

Electricity is relatively bad for heating things (compared e.g. to engines). OTOH you can use electricity on ground to generate fuels (PtX: Power to Gas/Liquid), which may be good because you can use the excess electricity on some time of most days (so also cheap)

It's not completely terrible. Ideas: helium-free tethered balloon, where power lines are easier than gas lines, or where payload power is beamed.

To a limited extent. There are electric fans for inflating hot air ballons, and electric maneuvering engines for balloons.
I haven't heard of anyone heating the air inside a balloon by electric means, although it seems easy enough to use an electric heat cannon for initial balloon inflation while on the ground. But even such cannons often combine propane heat with electric fans.
Using electricity to heat air isn't an environmental priority. Most electricity is produced by burning coal globally (although natural gas and nuclear have overtaken it in the most-developed countries). This heat-electricity-storage-heat conversion has an efficiency of 30%-50%, while burning propane directly, about 90%. The heater would also have to stay on the ground, supplied by AC grid power.
However, there does exist at least one solar-powered balloon. It doesn't use photovoltaics, but rather converts solar energy to heat directly, by being black on one side.

Perhaps one reason for limited innovation in hot air ballons is that a more environmentally sustainable alternative already exists: helium balloons. While helium is also in limited supply, coming as a byproduct of natural gas extraction, most of that helium isn't currently being collected.

Nope. the energy density of battery technology is way, way less than that of propane.  A battery source for heating the air inside a balloon would be far too heavy for the balloon to lift.

So much nope that even a (Chinese) patent for such a thing was allowed to quietly expire instead of paying the fee to preserve it.

I don't challenge your claims, but without figures to support them they look like opinions.

@CamilleGoudeseune Not saying the Chinese patent is or isn't practical, but many solid patents get abandoned for no better reason then they aren't commercially valuable enough to make paying fees reasonable.

First off, hot air balloons fly because we heat up the air inside that massive balloon (we call it the envelope), making the air less dense than the cooler air outside. This difference in density is what gets us floating up into the sky. Traditionally, we use propane burners—basically big ol' flamethrowers—to heat the air.
Now, could we swap out those propane burners for electric heaters? In theory, sure. But here's the thing: heating all that air requires a ton of energy. Electric heaters would need massive batteries, which are heavy. And adding heavy batteries to a balloon? Not exactly the best idea when you're trying to get airborne!
Developing an electric hot air balloon would involve a huge investment in research and technology to create lightweight, high-capacity batteries or super-efficient heaters. But here's the kicker: the hot air ballooning community is pretty small. We're a tight-knit group of enthusiasts, but there just aren't enough of us to make it a profitable venture for companies to pour resources into developing electric balloons.
So, while the idea is super cool, it's not really practical with our current technology and market size. Until there's a breakthrough that makes it feasible, we'll keep firing up the propane and enjoying those epic sunrise flights!
